# how to use mongodb patterns in logstash

Tags: logstash

In logstash there are several [predefined patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/mongodb) for a mongodb log.

However as there are multiple types of patterns (mongo_log, mongo_query etc) I am not sure how these should be used in a filter for parsing the mongodb.log file

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but your best bet is to validate your patterns with: http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ 
Also, different versions of mongo might have slightly different message structures, so these patterns may not be applicable in every version.

Comment: grokdebug does not provide the patterns that the OP is referencing